# Converting OpenCV 2.4 Random Forest Parameters to Scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have recently trained a Random Forest classifier to classify images using OpenCV 2.4 however, I encountered an error in saving the classifier to an XML file and decided to switch to Scikit-learn.

The cross-validation mean score in OpenCV resulted in 96.70% accuracy rate but when converted to Scikit-learn, the mean score decreased to only 91.75%.

Can anyone explain what parameters did I miss in converting the OpenCV code to Scikit-learn?

Here is my OpenCV code:

```
class Classify(object):

  def __init__(self, features, label)
    self.params = dict(max_depth=100,
                             min_sample_count=1,
                             use_surrogates=False,
                             max_categories=5,
                             calc_var_importance=False,
                             nactive_vars=0,
                             max_num_of_tree_in_the_forest=100,
                             term_crit=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,100,0.1))

    self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    self.le.fit(label)
    leLabels = np.array(self.le.transform(label), dtype=np.float32)
    features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, leLabels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    result = self.trainingForest(features_train, labels_train)
    self.crossValidation(result, features_test, labels_test)     #####call to manual computation of crossValidation score

  def trainingForest(self, features, label):
    features = np.array(features, dtype=np.float32)
    model = cv2.RTrees()
    model.train(features, cv2.CV_ROW_SAMPLE, label, params=self.params)
    #### model.save('tree.xml')              ###### the cause of the bug

  def crossValidation(self, model, features_test, labels_test):
    features_test = np.array(features_test, dtype=np.float32)
    predictionResult = []
    for item in features_test:
        res = self.model.predict(item)
        predictionResult.append(res)

    accuracy = (labels_test == predictionResult).mean()
    error = (labels_test != predictionResult).mean()

    print("Manual Accuracy Score: %.2f %%" % (accuracy * 100))
    print("Error: %.2f %%" % (error * 100))
    return
```

Here is my Scikit-learn code:

```
class ClassifierTrainer(object):
    def __init__(self, X, label_words):

        # Encoding the labels (words to numbers)
        self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

        self.clf = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=100, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=0, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

        y = self._encodeLabels(label_words)
        X = np.asarray(X)
        self.clf.fit(X, y)
        scores = cross_val_score(self.clf,X,y)
        print scores.mean()
```

Comment: Please also post the code of `crossValdiation`

Comment: done. I already added the cross-validation code